# how to simulate a rocket exhaust engine like shown below

Tags: texturing, volumetrics

Hell, i want to achieve this result of the rocket exhaust as shown below. this is from space x starship animation.

i tried volumetrics but didnt get quite the result.
a glare and a blur got me close but not there yet.
the photo show some volumetrics were used because the light is jagged.

am i missing something? is this achievable in blender and how.

thank you.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108702/mach-shock-diamonds-in-blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76728/rocket-engine-thrust-point-density-node https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48816/how-to-create-a-fire-light-effect-in-a-spaceship-engine

Comment: The first link is very useful. Thank you. Point density is useless. Blender crashes with point density animations. I submitted a bug report but blender developers has been aware of this bug since 2018 and they don't want to fix it ::